# Intel PIN: How to access the INS object from inside an analysis function?

Tags: c++, pintool

A typical PIN code snippet looks like this (taken from the [official manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/index.html#IAddressTrace)):

```
// This function is called before every instruction is executed
// and prints the IP
VOID printip(VOID *ip) { fprintf(trace, "%p\n", ip); }

// Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    // Insert a call to printip before every instruction, and pass it the IP
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)printip, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_END);
}
```

I just can't figure out how to access the `ins` object from within `printip(VOID *p)`. The other way round seems easy, i.e. getting the IP from from the `ins` object:

`INS_Address (INS ins)`(see [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#gd3b5f975c84b126531b38930b94b5544))

I tried passing a `INS *ins` pointer to `printip(VOID *ip, INS *ins)` ins via `IARG_PTR, &ins` but this ended in either casting errors or Segmentation faults.

How can I access the `ins` object (type `INS`) from inside an analysis function?

**Side note:** I got to this problem when trying to call `INS_Disassemble (INS ins)` for every executed instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may note that `printip` is a function pointer, it is lazily called internally by `Pin`; moreover `ins` is an *automatic variable* (it is passed into `Instruction` from the stack). Consequently, passing `&ins` into `printip` (through `IARG_PTR`), then using it will lead to segmentation faults.

`Pin` declares `INS` by specializing the class template `INDEX`, as you can observe the following declaration in `type_core.TLH`:

```
/*! @ingroup INS_BASIC_API
Handle for INS */  
typedef class INDEX<6> INS;
```

where *constructors and assignment operators* of class template `INDEX` are both default. So, *in principle*^^, we can always declare a persistent variable to share an object of `INS` between instrumentation and analysis functions, for example:

```
static INS per_ins;
...
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
  per_ins = ins;
  ...
}
...
VOID printip(VOID *ip)
{
  INS_Disassemble(per_ins);
}
```

This method does not work, unfortunately, this is an example for "well-typed program still can go wrong" in `C/C++`^^. Since `Pin` does not guarantee that internal variables, accessed by an object of type `INS`, are persistent in *analysis time*, the result of calling `INS_Disassemble(per_ins)` in an *analysis function* can be meaningless.

For your case, you may not want to call `INS_Disassemble(ins)` each time `ins` executes. We don't need that, for example, if `ins` is in a loop then this function will be called multiple times (with the same `ins`) to get the same result.

All **static information** of an instruction (e.g. the disassembled form of `ins` in this case) should be obtained in *instrumentation time*. Particularly, `INS_Disassemble` should be called single time only in some instrumentation function. One way to obtain the same effect as you want is:

```
static std::unordered_map<ADDRINT, std::string> str_of_ins_at;

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
  str_of_ins_at[INS_Address(ins)] = INS_Disassemble(ins);
  ...
}

VOID printip(VOID *ip, ADDRINT addr) 
{
  std::string ins_str = str_of_ins_at[addr];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I wanted to place the `INS_Disassemble(ins)` into the analysis function to check (manually by looking at it) if the analysis function works as intended. If I place the `INS_Disassemble(ins)` into the Instrumentation function, the output of `INS_Disassemble(ins)` is separated from the output of the analysis function. In other words: I wanted the output of the analysis function be entitled with the instruction to easily check if it is correct.

Comment: You are correct, we can always obtain opcode of an instruction using `PIN_SafeCopy` and `INS_Size`, then use whatever disassemble tool e.g. Capstone, or even Xed of Intel.

Comment: Oh sorry, I deleted my comment regarding this approach because your idea to store the strings looked more elegant to me.

Comment: But anyway, great explanation of what is going on with this `ins` object.

Answer (score 1):

typedef class INDEX<6> INS; is defined in types_core.TLH (types not type). The following code works for me to disassamble at analysis time.

```
void disasmIns(ADDRINT tid, ADDRINT insarg)
{
  INS ins;
  ins.q_set(insarg);
  std::cout << "Disassembly: " << INS_Disassemble(ins) << std::endl;
}

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v) {
  INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)disasmIns, 
  IARG_FAST_ANALYSIS_CALL, IARG_ADDRINT, ins.q(), IARG_END);
}
```